# Variable name undefined in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6

I am running it with Rails-React to return the data from database (mongoDB). Had successfully connect with the DB. However, it returns error "TypeError: home_fires is undefined", please help...

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    let home_fires = type.string;
    this.state = {
        error: null,
        isLoaded: false,
        home_fires: []
    };
}

componentDidMount() {
    fetch("http://localhost:3000/api/home_fires")
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(
            (results) => {
                this.setState({
                    isLoaded: true,
                    home_fires: results.home_fires
                });
            },

            (error) => {
                this.setState({
                    isLoaded: true,
                    error
                });
            }
        )
}
```

Here is how I render the data,`{this.props.home_fires.map(this.homefire)} ( ...`

Comment: where you are using `home_fires` inside same component or in child? if in same then it should be `this.state.home_fires.map`

Comment: where and how is `home_fires` being accessed? that will shed light on the issue

Comment: I believe you meant to use `this.state.home_fires.map...` and not `this.props..`.

Comment: @MayankShukla yes it is in the same component. i have try {this.state.home_fires.map} {home_fires.map(homefire => (... } it return the same error

Comment: I'm not sure, but something telling me the error might coming from my componentDidMount or Constructor, but just couldnt figure out what...

Comment: Try to set a breakpoint in your devTools in your fetch call, just right after the second then `.then(results) => ...` to see if you're getting the correct result.

Comment: please post the data that your are getting from the server (`results`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your map function should be like

```
this.props.home_fires.map(home_fire => <div>{home_fire.bla}</div>)
```

Also, if you are calling home_fires in the same component, it should be,

```
this.state.home_fires
```

Comment: unfortunately, I have tried your code... the error still presists, TypeError: home_fires undefined ...

Comment: Hmm, use react devtools and check your with it first https://github.com/facebook/react-devtools

Comment: have used react-devtools to check my code, it doesn't render the body.. mostly caused by the TypeError...

Comment: I see. Then first remove the render code and check the state

Comment: it returns only blank result.. oh my god.. please help, im stuck in this part for more than an hour

Comment: I know it will only render a blank result. How is the react inspector doing? Is it having the state that you expected?

Comment: it did not.. is it because the error at componentdidmount or constructor?

Comment: I think it is because of the componentdidmount

Comment: Yup, indeed it is, now I using another method (ajax) and the TypeError is solved. Attempting to bring the data to view now. Thank you very much for your help anyway!

Comment: Great! If the problem has solved. Finish the question as this guide says. https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because of constructor, just remove

> let home_fires = type.string;